# SSH2 library for ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, networking, ssl, ssh

Is there any quality SSH2 library for ios?

For java there's a library called jsch (http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) that does a great job at wrapping ssh2.  The one bit of functionality that I'm most interested in is the "Reverse Port Forward" method:

```
session.setPortForwardingR(remote_port, host, local_port);
```

I found one objective-c lib from http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ssh-sftp-objc.asp, but it's not free and doesn't seem to be at a high level of quality.  Should I just attempt to port the C version of openssh?

Also, if porting openssh is the best option, is there any open source project that is currently doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might consider checking out [libssh](http://www.libssh.org/).  At first glance it looks like an appealing option for C.  It can probably be compiled for iPhone with a bit of effort.

Comment: Not a bad idea, I'm going to wait around for a little bit to see if anyone has any hints about compiling it.

Comment: Googling will locate a few iOS build tutorials. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

https://github.com/Lejdborg/NMSSH - 
https://github.com/x2on/libssh2-for-iOS